# python append list incrementing variable name

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have a lot of variables,

```
df_foo_1_100 = 4
df_foo_1_1000 = 5
...
df_foo_1_1000000 = 100

df_foo_2_100 = 9 
df_foo_2_1000 = 10 
df_foo_2_1000000 = -100

df_foo_4_100 = -1000
```

and have empty list, `temp=[]`
How can this empty list hold all variables using loop?

This is my code,

```
index = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
index2 = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
for i in index:
    for j in index2:
        temp.append(df_foo_{0}_{1}.format(i, j))
```

but didn't get any luck.
How can I fix this loop, so that I can have the output,

```
[df_1_100, df_1_1000... ]
```

(Inside of list is not string, but name of variables)

========== edit ==========
dict is fine as well.
the result `dict` will be like,
{df_foo_1_100: 4, df_foo_1_1000: 5 ...}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the **values** of all the variables in the list ?

Comment: Whenever you have "lot of variables" like this, it's a code smell. You should be using a collection like a list, a dict, or similar. Moving data between arrays is trivial. Operating on local variables as if they were a collection is not. You can abuse `locals()`, but note that it is a workaround for a bad practice.

Comment: @canadadry Yes. then will values be in order? if df_1_100 = 4 and df_1_1000 = 5, can result `list` be [4,5] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try elevate the `exec` function.

```
index = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
index2 = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
for i in index:
    for j in index2:
        exec("temp_variable = df_foo_{0}_{1}".format(i, j))
        temp.append(temp_variable)
```

Comment: Thank you. what if I want to have `dict` instead of `list` ?

Comment: what are the keys and values for `temp = {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way to get the value of the variable by the name. You can manually add them to a `dict`, or you can use the `locals()` builtin to do this.

```
df_foo_1_100 = "test_1_100"
df_foo_1_1000 = "test_1_1000"
df_foo_1_10000 = "test_1_10000"

df_foo_2_100 = "test_2_100"
df_foo_2_1000 = "test_2_1000"
df_foo_2_10000 = "test_2_10000"

df_foo_4_100 = "test_4_100"
df_foo_4_1000 = "test_4_1000"
df_foo_4_10000 = "test_4_10000"

df_foo_7_100 = "other_junk" # Not included...                                                                                                                                                               

import itertools
index1 = ["1", "2", "4"]
index2 = ["100", "1000", "10000"]
all_index_combos = list(itertools.product(index1, index2))
all_index_variables = set(["df_foo_{0}_{1}".format(ind1, ind2) for ind1, ind2 in all_index_combos])
dfs = [var for name, var in locals().items() if name in all_index_variables]
print(dfs)
```

this outputs

```
['test_1_100', 'test_1_1000', 'test_1_10000', 'test_2_100', 'test_2_1000', 'test_2_10000', 'test_4_100', 'test_4_1000', 'test_4_10000']
```

as desired.

If you want a `dict`, just change

```
dfs = [var for name, var in locals().items() if name in all_index_variables]
```

to

```
dfs = dict([(name, var) for name, var in locals().items() if name in all_index_variables])
```

which will output:

```
{'df_foo_1_100': 'test_1_100', 'df_foo_1_1000': 'test_1_1000', 'df_foo_1_10000': 'test_1_10000', 'df_foo_2_100': 'test_2_100', 'df_foo_2_1000': 'test_2_1000', 'df_foo_2_10000': 'test_2_10000', 'df_foo_4_100': 'test_4_100', 'df_foo_4_1000': 'test_4_1000', 'df_foo_4_10000': 'test_4_10000'}
```